# how to pick up a the newest record from a list of values in a column

Tags: obiee

I have a requirement to write a code in OBIEE analysis to pick the newest score for a candidate, such that if `01/05/2018`  the took a test and scored say 75 then retook the same test in `3/15/2018`  and scored  `95`, i want my code to return `95` only.  how do i accomplish this in obiee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the aggregation rule for the measure to LAST. Either for the time dimension only or - which in the case of a test score would make sense - for all dimensions.

Comment: There is no LAST in the aggregate rule, unless i am not understanding your direction, i looked and all i see is None, MAX, Complex, MIn, Server dertermined and Default

Comment: In the RPD! That's where such logic should be. Not in the analysis where you need to redo if for every single time the measure is used.

Comment: Test score is column not a dimension, does that make a difference?

Comment: "column"...I hope you mean "measure"

Comment: when i change the aggregate rule to last, consistency check fails,any more suggetions?

Comment: HOW does it fail?  With what error? tl;dr LAST is the way to go but your RPD seems to be having issues in any case

Comment: I put this one aside for now to work at it at a later date. Thanks for your help.